# Nvidia-smi fails on AWS's g4ad server with deep learning AMI

Tags: nvidia, deep-learning-ami

I'm trying to use AWS's g4ad instance with deep learning AMI (Deep Learning AMI ([Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29)) Version 50.0) and when I'm trying to execute:

```
nvidia-smi
```

I'm getting:

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Nevertheless, it seems that CUDA is working fine. When executing `nvcc --version`, I'm getting:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Oct_12_20:09:46_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.105
Build cuda_11.1.TC455_06.29190527_0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, g4ad instances don't have an [Nvidia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia) GPU, but an [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Micro_Devices) GPU. With g4dn it works perfectly.